# How to use NestedScrollView into CollapsingToolbarLayout on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

In my application I should use `NestedScrollView` into `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
In this `NestedScrollView` I show many views and data but not scrolled in `NestedScrollView` and not show all of views!

**My XML codes:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.ControllableAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <!--Header layout-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverHeader"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size250">
                        <!--Cover blur image-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverBlurImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size250"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                        <!--Cover Shadow-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverShadow"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size250"
                            android:background="@color/black40"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                        <!--Avatar-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_avatarImage"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size80"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size80"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/celebrityDetail_celebrityName"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
                        <!--Celebrity Name-->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_celebrityName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/celebrityDetail_topTenImage"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font18" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                                            <!--Award-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_awardLay"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrityDetail_birthDiedLine"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardTitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/awards"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />
                        <!--Academy award-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardTitle"
                            android:visibility="visible">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/academyAwards"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />
                            <!--Nominations-->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/nominations"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <!--Won-->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedLay">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/wins"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size80"
                                android:layout_below="@id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderTitle" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <!--Line-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardLine"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size0.2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:alpha="0.3"
                            android:background="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                            android:visibility="visible" />
                        <!--Golden Globe-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardLine"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/goldenGlobe"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/nominations"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedCoundTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedLay">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/wins"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderTitle"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrityDetail_birthDiedLay" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarBack"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_image"
                        android:tint="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarSearch"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarBack"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                        android:shadowDx="1"
                        android:shadowDy="1"
                        android:shadowRadius="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarSearch"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/size3"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                        android:tint="@color/white" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.PlusTabLayout.TabLayoutPlus
            android:id="@+id/celebrity_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/celebrity_toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size3"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size3"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/size3"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/allCapsTabLayout"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

    </app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.ControllableAppBarLayout>

    <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.DisableSwipeViewPager
        android:id="@+id/celebrity_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrity_tabLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/celebrity_ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.ControllableAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <!--Header layout-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverHeader"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size250">
                        <!--Cover blur image-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverBlurImage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size250"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                        <!--Cover Shadow-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_coverShadow"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size250"
                            android:background="@color/black40"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                        <!--Avatar-->
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_avatarImage"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/size80"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size80"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/celebrityDetail_celebrityName"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
                        <!--Celebrity Name-->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_celebrityName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/celebrityDetail_topTenImage"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font18" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                                            <!--Award-->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_awardLay"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrityDetail_birthDiedLine"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardTitle"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text="@string/awards"
                            android:textColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />
                        <!--Academy award-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardTitle"
                            android:visibility="visible">
                            <!--Title-->
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/academyAwards"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />
                            <!--Nominations-->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/nominations"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>
                            <!--Won-->
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size40"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyNominatedLay">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/wins"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyWinsTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size80"
                                android:layout_below="@id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderTitle" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <!--Line-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardLine"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/size0.2"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardAcademyHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:alpha="0.3"
                            android:background="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                            android:visibility="visible" />
                        <!--Golden Globe-->
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderLay"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardLine"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding5"
                            android:visibility="visible">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="@string/goldenGlobe"
                                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font14" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/nominations"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedCoundTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsLay"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/size100"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenNominatedLay">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:text="@string/wins"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsCountTxt"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/size2"
                                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenWinsTxt"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circle_primary_color"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font12" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenRecyclerView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/infoMovieFrag_AwardGoldenHeaderTitle"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size20"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrityDetail_birthDiedLay" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarBack"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding5"
                        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_image"
                        android:tint="@color/white" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarSearch"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarBack"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                        android:shadowDx="1"
                        android:shadowDy="1"
                        android:shadowRadius="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/celebrityDetail_toolbarSearch"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/size30"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                        android:padding="@dimen/size3"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
                        android:tint="@color/white" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.PlusTabLayout.TabLayoutPlus
            android:id="@+id/celebrity_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/celebrity_toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size3"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/size3"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/size3"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/allCapsTabLayout"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

    </app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.ControllableAppBarLayout>

    <app.test.com.Utils.Componenets.DisableSwipeViewPager
        android:id="@+id/celebrity_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/celebrity_tabLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/celebrity_ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size25"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```